# Tips how to solve limit of $2$ variables Euler limit?

Tags: limits

I need your help to solve this limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}(1+yx^2)^{(1/(x^2+y^2))}.$$

I think this connected to $e$, but I don't know to get there.
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Let me suggest that in order to give your post more [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), as is generally expected for posts on this site, you could explain more why you think this is connected to $e$. That would definitely improve your question and help avoid close votes.

Comment: hey, this is my first question. 
i think this connected to e because of the formula- lim x->0 of (1+x)^1/x=e. that all i got

Comment: I tied a polar show and i didn't progress to far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you tried with polar coordinates, but in general we require that you write your work or it is unhealty for your studies to just read the full solution. Hence, I'll give you just some hints.

Since $1+yx^2>0$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, using $a^b=e^{\log a^b}$ which is valid for $a>0$ and using properties of logarithm it is:
$$\left(1+yx^2\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}=\exp\left[{{\frac{\log(1+yx^2)}{x^2+y^2}}}\right]$$
From the Taylor's expansion of $\log(1+t)$ for $t \to 0$, it is $\log(1+t)=t+\text{o}(t)$ and so, since $yx^2 \to 0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, it is:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{\log(1+yx^2)}{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{yx^2+\text{o}(yx^2)}{x^2+y^2}}$$
And it is not difficult to show that the latter fraction tends to $0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.